# Using Flickr API via Objective-C with normal login/password

Tags: objective-c, flickr

I am trying to use Flickr API via Objective-C. Can I get a user-related information like shared pictures just using login and password that user has used to register in Flickr? Or the user needs to get key/secret pair bound to a particular application?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some of the Flickr tutorials out there, but I believe you need an api token from Flickr to pull in the image feed.

Here is the tutorial I used, which also contains links to get your api key.

[iPhone JSON Flickr Tutorial Pt 1](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html)

Comment: You are welcome. If you think this answer will suffice, please consider accepting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The framework 'ObjectiveFlickr' is by far the best tool for the job here:
https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr

I've used it in heaps of projects.

It'll manage all your API authentication and requests.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't just use a username and password to access private information. Yahoo/Flickr use OAuth which is a bit more involved. There are also a few open source Flickr API frameworks that should do a lot of the work for you. (I've not used any myself, hence the lack of a recommendation.)